# how to increase a number value on button click jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

html

```
<span id="count" style="margin-top: -5%;" class="likes_count">5 likes</span>
```

this is my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // when the user clicks on like
    $(document).on('click','.like',function(){
       $('.like').addClass('animated bounceIn');
      var postid = $(this).data('id');
      var id = $(this).attr('data-likes');
          $post = $(this);

      $.ajax({
        url: 'dashboard.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          'liked': 1,
          'postid': postid
        },
        success: function(response){


          $post.parent().find('span.likes_count').text(id+1+"likes");
          $post.addClass('hide');
          $post.siblings().removeClass('hide');



        }
      });

    });
```

i am fetching nuber of like in id variable but dont know how to increase it on success ive tried it in my code but not working it is adding 1 in front of the whole number any helps

Comment: Can you add any live demo ? with HTML code ?

Comment: `...text(parseInt(id)+1+"likes")`

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this:

```
$post.parent().find('span.likes_count').text(id+1+"likes");
```

with:

```
$post.parent().find('span.likes_count').text((+id+1)+"likes");
```

The problem is that `id`, as well as `"likes"` are strings, so Javascript interprets the `+` operator as doing concatenation between strings. The "unary plus" `+id` converts it to a number (you can also use `Number(id)`, which some find more explicit but I personally find verbose), and by putting `+id+1` in parentheses you ensure that this is treated as numeric addition, before the string concatentation with `"likes"` happens.